# Error using anonymous enums as function arguments in lldb

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, lldb

I have a class, `MyClass`, with an overloaded `[]` operator that takes an anonymous enum of type `MyEnum`. I can use it fine in code, but cannot inspect the object using lldb. When I try , I get the following error . .

```
(lldb) p myObject[MyEnum::value]
error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'MyClass'
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'MyEnum' (aka '<anonymous enum>') for 1st argument
```

Can anyone explain why the debugger will not convert the enum properly?

[xcode 5.1.1]

Comment: Is this only reproducable in the debugger? Or can you make a test case that causes a similar compiler error?

Comment: This is only reproducible in the debugger

Comment: Have you tried casting? `p myObject[(MyEnum)MyEnum::value]`

Comment: @trojanfoe no I hadn't and that seems to work. Thanks. Add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you can make a small example that shows this, please file a bug with the example at bugreporter.apple.com.  It doesn't seem like that cast should be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you need to cast the enumeration:

```
p myObject[(MyEnum)MyEnum::value]
           ^^^^^^^^
```